# Splunk: use quoted parameter in request

Tags: logging, splunk

I have quoted parameters in log files, which are processed by Splunk:

```
"Version":"21"
```

How to extract that parameter to use in requests like this:

```
Version = "21" OR ...
```

Please note that it's no chance to modify current Splunk's config files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting escaped quotes around the values, like

```
\"Version\" = "\"21\""
```

This may pick up on the quotes in the values.

Comment: Yes I did. `0 matching events`.